# How to store a private key using JCE

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, private-key, jce

I am very new to the JCA, so forgive any simple mistakes I have made. I am attempting to familiarize myself with the Java cryptography suite. I am working on putting a private key into a KeyStore of my own. Whenever I place the file into the keystore, no problems. The encoding is PKCS #8, as it should be. The problem, however, is when I go to retrieve the key, it says that this key cannot be recovered because it was not placed in the keystore under the PKCS #8 format. Her is my code to insert the key

```
    public static void saveToKeyStore(Key key, String password, String alias)
{
    try
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

        InputStream readStream = null;
        File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.etc/.keystore");

        if(tmpFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("file exists");
            readStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.etc/.keystore");
            ks.load(readStream, password.toCharArray());
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("file doesn't exist");
            ks.load(null, password.toCharArray());

            tmpFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        }



        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key.getEncoded());

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PrivateKey tempKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        System.out.println("encoding format: " + tempKey.getFormat());

        ks.setKeyEntry(alias, tempKey.getEncoded(), null);

        OutputStream writeStream = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.etc/.keystore");

        ks.store(writeStream, password.toCharArray());

        System.out.println("key was created: " + ks.isKeyEntry(alias));

        writeStream.close();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my code to retrieve the key

```
    public static Key retrieveFromKeyStore(String password, String alias)
{
    Key returnKey = null;
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    try
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

        InputStream readStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.etc/.keystore");

        ks.load(readStream, password.toCharArray());


        System.out.println("is a key: " + alias + " \n well?: " + ks.isKeyEntry(alias));

        System.out.println("return key encoding format: " + ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray()));

        returnKey = ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(returnKey.getEncoded()));

        if(privateKey != null)
        {
            System.out.println("privateKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("return key was null");
        }

        readStream.close();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return privateKey;
}
```

Any help on this matter or references to good material on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn't valid to store a `PrivateKey` without a certificate chain of length at least 1.

Comment: Thanks a bunch that was it! Still pretty new to security concepts in general, especially keys an certificates. Thanks again for the advice. Good catch.